# react native - firestore data able to show on console.log but not able to show on screen

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore

i'm try to fetch data from firestore and  display data in react native screen

```
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, async (user) => {
    if (user) {
      setUser(user);
      const uid = user.email;
      const uemail = user.email;
      const q = query(
      collection(db, "student"), where("studentEmail", "==", uemail));
      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data()); /*data showing on console */
        console.log(doc.data());
      });
      } else {     
      }
      });
```

**Error - not showing data in react native screen**

```
return (
<View\>
<Text style={styles.name}>{doc.Address}\</Text\>  
</View\>
)
```

Comment: What is doc in doc.address? Include the code of it's declaration

Comment: @TayyabMazhar doc field ->  {"Address": "Test"} , i try to display address value